# React Hook “useInterval” cannot be called inside a callback

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-hooks

I'm trying to setup a progress bar for a backend action that can take a while to complete.

1. User click button to export a file
2. API response has a token for the backend process
3. With useInterval, I check every half a second the progress % (with another endpoint, sending the token) to update my progress bar component

I simplified the code in Codesandbox to reproduce the problem, in my Codesandbox, when clicking the button, I run useInterval to get a new random cat picture every 4 seconds and update my hook.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pw2q9)

As I understand, the problem is because I'm calling a Hook inside a custom Hook (useInterval), but I don't know another way to do this because native setInterval does not work with Hooks.

I used the **use-interval** package

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to wrap `useInterval` with `useEffect`. [Internally](https://github.com/donavon/use-interval/blob/45b130d4d982cc3bb53cd5d5259eec9194b52e63/src/index.js#L3) `useInterval` calls `useEffect` to do it work.

And you can change values passed to `useInterval` in component and new values will be applied correctly. You can change delay or callback arguments and `useInterval` will apply them.

To showcase, I've added stop button, which stops retrieving cats.

Here is [working solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/useinterval-nylhv) with cats :-)

Comment: Oh, funny that I didn't even think about putting the useInterval outside the side effect.